# Why the migrator aptitude are different about different books?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In Solomons 8th

H> phenyl >3 order alkyl > 2order alkyl >1 order alkyl > methyl

In Wade 8th or Bruice 5th, they also means

H > 3 order >2 order ≈phenyl > 1 order

why the description are different about phenyl?

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10833/migratory-aptitude-in-pinacol-pinacolone-rearrangement/16470#16470