# Migratory aptitude of substituents for carbonation rearrangement in Pinnacol Pinnacolone rearrangment

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Generally, the observed migratory aptitude for carbocation rearrangement is (as given in various books)  :

$$\ce{H- > Ph- >CH_3-}$$

But the fact is that the carbocation at the benzylic carbon is more stable.

This is counter-intuitive, so what is a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: @JaideepKhare You aren't aware of the `\ce` notation for chemical equations. Do check out https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here before suggesting wrong edits

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Thanks, I wasn't knowing about that notation of chemical equations., (I am mostly active on Math SE.)I'll take care next time.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/migratory-preference-in-a-rearrangement-involving-carbocations